# Falcon 9 legs: precharged helium?

Tags: falcon-9, vertical-landing, helium

I've read the Falcon 9 uses helium pneumatics to extend its legs.

The separation pushers are also helium pneumatics and I believe those are precharged so no pumps required.

Are the leg cylinders precharged too?

Comment: Pumps for the helium?

Comment: There has to be a pressure source. What is that pressure source---that's my question.

Comment: No  specific knowledge, but I would be surprised if it isn't high pressure bottles.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm thinking too. I know nothing about how helium systems would work---not on a rocket and not on any other machine. I just know it'll need a pressure source, I guess. The legs are single-use (they deploy only once and that's it), so a precharge would probably be simpler and required fewer parts than alternatives (of which I won't pretend to know anything). Would love it if someone could confirm (or dispute) that the helium is precharged.